# Storing array of structures for a class

Tags: arrays, swift, class, structure

i am wondering the best way to store an array of structures.

i have a `Movie` structure that has a name and an image associated to it

```
struct Movie {
    var name = ""
    var image = ""
}
```

and a `Person` who has a favouriteMovie, which he/she can only pick from the static array of `movies`

```
class Person {
    static let movies = [Movie(name: "movie 1", image: "movie-1.png"),
        Movie(name: "movie 2", image: "movie-2.png")]
    var movie = Movie()
}
```

is this an efficient way of storing the array of structures?

for example i could have many `Person` instances being initiated and the list of `movies` could grow.

```
var alex1 = Person()
alex1.movie = movies[0]
var alex2 = Person()
alex2.movie = movies[0]

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit more efficient to only store a key (index, for example) of each movie inside the `Person` object. Of course, you then have to guarantee that the array of movies doesn't invalidate those keys without re-mapping all the objects.

I'd also keep the movies array with the Movie object. It's a bit more logical.

```
struct Movie {
  static let movies = [
    Movie(name: "movie 1", image: "movie-1.png"),
    Movie(name: "movie 2", image: "movie-2.png")]
  let name:String
  let image:String
}


class Person {
  var movieIndex:Int = 0
  var movie:Movie? {
    get {
      return Movie.movies[movieIndex]
    }
  }
}

var alex1 = Person()
alex1.movieIndex = 0
var alex2 = Person()
alex2.movieIndex = 1

alex1.movie?.name // "movie-1.png"
alex2.movie?.name // "movie-2.png"
```

Comment: thanks. so if I'm right the `static let movies = ...` only gets called once i.e. i'm not generating repeated instances of this constant - it just references one copy? :-/

Comment: Right, when you have a `let` statement it only gets set once and references that single object. This is a good thing because it's something that isn't likely to change much, due to it being a store for indexed items. When you need to add more you can just program in more and add them to the end. If you need something that changes more frequently then you have to re-think this.

Comment: yes it won't change, and if it does i'll hard code it. is this the "cleanest" way of setting a constant array in Swift (looks a bit messy)? and for clarity, i was meaning the `static` part - does this mean it only references the original structure rather than an instance of it?

Comment: The statement `static` means that it's a feature of the class itself and not instances of the class. So yes, it won't be created every time you instantiate that class and only one copy of that variable will ever be created. It is pretty clean, although it would perhaps be even cleaner to have an external file that you read from if you have a decent number of movies.

Comment: @KennethBruno: inside `Movie`, the properties `name` and `image` should **not** be `var` and should **not** have a default value. They should be declared as follow `let name:String    let image: String`

Comment: @appzYourLife True, I simply followed the format in the original question. It would be better to do it as you said, I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @KennethBruno: very well and +1

Comment: @appzYourLife To you too. Sometimes we can't see the forest for the trees. It's always useful to have that kind of stuff pointed out.

Comment: @KennethBruno: Another note. `Person.movieIndex` should **not** have a default value of `0`. Otherwise we are assuming that `Movie.movies[0]` is the default favourited movie. **If** a `Person` must always have a favourite `Movie` then `movieIndex` should be declared as `let movieIndex: Int` and the initializer of `Person` should receive that value. On the other hand if a `Person` can have no favourite movie, `movieIndex` should be `Int?`

Comment: @appzYourLife Yeah, I left it like that just to make the example simple. I agree that either of your ideas would be a better fit.